# Installing bhoogle through stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hoogle

I'm [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoogle)

And see:

```
Command Line UI

There is a terminal/curses based UI available through cabal install bhoogle.
```

I'd like to install with stack rather than cabal.  I run

```
$ stack install hoogle
Copied executables to /home/username/.local/bin:
- bhoogle
```

This is on my path, great.  Let's run it:

```
$ bhoogle

bhoogle error:     default hoogle database not found
     at /home/username/.hoogle/default-haskell-5.0.17.hoo    You can create the database by installing hoogle and running
     hoogle generate
```

Great, let's do that:

```
$ hoogle generate

Command 'hoogle' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install hoogle
```

How about calling it bhoogle instead?

```
$ bhoogle generate

bhoogle error: 
   default hoogle database not found
     at /home/username/.hoogle/default-haskell-5.0.17.hoo
   You can create the database by installing hoogle and running
     hoogle generate
```

Is it not finding the executable?  Let's use the full path:

```
$ /home/username/.local/bin/bhoogle generate

bhoogle error: 
   default hoogle database not found
     at /home/username/.hoogle/default-haskell-5.0.17.hoo
   You can create the database by installing hoogle and running
     hoogle generate
```

How can I initialize hoogle?

Comment: bhoogle is a front-end to an existing hoogle database.  What do you have in your "~/.hoogle" directory?  You should have two files, default-haskell-5.0.17.hoo and default-haskell-5.0.17.warn,  do you?  

Additionally, your hoogle version and your bhoogle version need to match, at this point, it's 5.0.17.

Comment: I do not have a ~/.hoogle directory.  The `stack install hoogle` appears to have only made a bhoogle binary, but made no .hoogle.  Isn't ~/.hoogle created by the generate call?

Comment: When you run "hoogle generate" the database will be created, did it succeed?

Comment: Sounds like you're just confused about the difference between bhoogle and hoogle. You must install both for bhoogle to work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer was running:

```
stack install hoogle
```

twice.

The first time it installed many packages and said:

```
$ stack install hoogle
Copied executables to /home/username/.local/bin:
- bhoogle
```

The second time it installed no packages and said:

```
$ stack install hoogle
Copying from /home/username/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-12.6/8.4.3/bin/hoogle to /home/username/.local/bin/hoogle

Copied executables to /home/username/.local/bin:
- hoogle
```

Comment: "stack install hoogle" will not install bhoogle.  I suspect you made a typo, check your terminal history.